# Mingw runtime error

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, mingw

I'm a new user of MinGW, and I have already run into problems. When attempting to compile a very simple Hello world c++ program, I get an error. I type the command:

```
g++ hello.cpp -o hello.exe
```

and then I get the message dialog:

```
Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library
Runtime Error!

Program: c:\mingw\bin\...\libexec\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\cc1plus.exe

R6034:
An application has made an attempt to load the C Runtime library incorrectly.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

followed immediately by this message dialog:

```
cc1plus.exe - Program error

The application failed to initialize properly
(0xc0000142). Press OK to close application.
```

And then the usual junk about Windows finding a solution online.

I used the automatic installer `mingw-get-setup.exe` and simply followed the instructions. I chose the installation folder to be `C:\mingw`, and in the MinGW Installation Manager, I chose to install `mingw-developer-toolkit`, `mingw32-base`, `mingw32-gcc-g++`, `mingw32-gcc-objc` and `msys-base`. As suggested in the installation guide, I added `PATH` in the `Environment Variables`.

The code I was trying to compile was:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char ** argv){
    cout << "hello world" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I also tried to compile a similar ANSI-C code with the command:

```
gcc hello.c -o hello.exe
```

and I got the same error.

I tried the command in `cmd.exe` as well as in MSYS and got the error in both cases. My operating system is Windows Vista Home Premium, and I have Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 installed on it. I mention this because I tried to do the same installation on a windows 7 computer without VC++ and here the compiler worked without problems. Does this mean that you can't have MinGW and VC++ on the same computer?

Comment: It seem as the mingw compiler is trying to load VC++ CRT library, you are executing the command in a normal cmd or in a VS cmd? There is no problem using mingw with VC++ installed, i have in the same machine vs2012, vs2013, mingw32 and mingw64

Comment: On Windows, some applications improperly put their own versions of the VC runtime in %PATH%. This breaks other applications. Check if you can reproduce this with an empty %PATH%.

Comment: @NetVipeC: I use the normal cmd

Comment: @n.m.: I tried to remove the %PATH% and then I got a new error: `cc1plus.exe - The component was not found. The program was unable to start because libgmp-10.dll was not found. The problem may be resolved by reinstalling the program.` (translated from Danish)

Comment: You probably need to keep those components of PATH that Mingw itself adds.

Comment: @n.m.: I think you are on to something here. The %PATH% variable contained only the value for Mingw, which is C:\mingw\bin. And it is not allowed to leave the value blank. However, I tried to remove %PATH%, put the cpp code into to the C:\mingw\bin folder and then run the command. And it worked! Of course, putting all my code in to the bin folder is not really a solution.

Comment: You can use MingGW with an empty PATH and keep your code its own directory by using the full pathname of gcc. eg: `c:\mingw\bin\gcc hello.c -o hello.exe`. But to solve your problem you need to find the improperly installed application that n.m. referred to and remove its directory from your PATH when using MinGW. Go through every directory listed in your PATH and look for a file called `msvcrt.dll`. Skip the one in `c:\Windows\System32`, as that's what MinGW should be using. Any other copy that you find is likely the one causing you problems, so remove that directory from your PATH.

Comment: @n.m.: You where right all along. The user variable %PATH% contained only MinGW's value, but then I noticed a _system_ variable also with the name %PATH%. This contained some values from MatLab and MikTex, and once I got rid of those, the compiler worked just fine. This problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, as suggested in the comments, that programs other than the Gnu Compiler had left values in the %PATH% variable. What I did not initially notice, was the fact that there are *two* %PATH% variables, one for the user and one for the system, and both can interfere with the MinGW installation.

The system %PATH% variable contains (at least on my PC) quite a lot of entries and removing all of them might not be a good idea. In my case, however, it was sufficient to remove entries from MatLab and Texnic Center. Afterwards, g++ and gcc worked flawless.